# How to update checkbox via event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, datagrid

In a WPF app, I have a DataGrid with a checkbox column.  At some point, I loop through data and determine that some rows in the DataGrid need to be checked.

What approach can be use so each grid row is updated as the above looping determines the row should be checked. I'd like the checks to appear one by one as the user waits. I believe this means the back end thread can't block.

Comment: Try using MVVM structure and bind collection of the class to the data grid, so that you can update the bool variable that is bound with checkbox will be updated when you update the bool variable in code behind.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Have a look at the sample created in the blog: http://wpftution.blogspot.ca/2012/05/mvvm-sample-using-datagrid-control-in.html

Comment: For your case, you will need to have a boolean variabled defined in the class that you wish to bind to datagrid and then you can update that boolean in background thread or another thread and that will reflected on the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox needs to be bound to a Boolean via `TwoWay` binding which reports a NotifyPropertyChanged type notification. When that Boolean is changed either in the GUI or in the backend, the notification will change it on the screen.